# python-docxを用いた図の貼り付けと図番の付け方について

Tags: python, python3, docx, python-docx

wordで作成中のレポートに追加で大量の図を貼り付ける必要が出たため、python-docxで図とその図番号を貼り付けようとしています。

以下のページを参考に図の貼り付けと図番号の作成を行いました。

[python-docxを使ってみた](https://qiita.com/hawaii_hahaha/items/44a4128c2a91a27a6e84)

結果として図の貼り付けは上手くいったのですが、field更新をしても図番号の表示がFigure0-８０のように謎の0と80が全角になってしまいます。
(例：wordで作成した最後の図番号がFigure 79の場合、python docxで作成した図番号はページの最後にあるとFIgre0-８０になる)
どなたかこの図番号の0の消去と80の部分を半角に直す方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

OSのversionはWindows10
wordは2016
pythonは3.9.12
python-docxのversionは0.8.11

参考のためにコードの該当部分を以下に載せておきます。

```
from docx import Document
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn
from docx.shared import Inches
from attrdict import AttrDict

from pathlib import Path

word_path = Path(r'C:\Users\Documents')
fig_path = word_path/'figure'

def Figure(elm,paragraph):
    run = paragraph.add_run()
    r = run._r

    fldChar = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
    fldChar.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'begin')
    r.append(fldChar)

    instrText = OxmlElement('w:instrText')
    instrText.text = u' STYLEREF 2 \s'
    r.append(instrText)

    fldChar = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
    fldChar.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'end')
    r.append(fldChar)

    run = paragraph.add_run(u'－')

    run = paragraph.add_run()
    r = run._r
    fldChar = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
    fldChar.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'begin')
    r.append(fldChar)

    instrText = OxmlElement('w:instrText')
    instrText.text = u' SEQ Figure \* DBCHAR'
    r.append(instrText)

    fldChar = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
    fldChar.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'end')
    r.append(fldChar)

    run = paragraph.add_run(u'　'+elm)


document = Document(word_path/'test.docx')

p = document.add_paragraph(u'文の挿入 ')
p.add_run(u'太字').bold = True
p.add_run(' and some ')
p.add_run(u'斜線.').italic = True

document.add_heading(u'見出し１', level=1)
document.add_paragraph(u'本文１で長い文章をかいてもらいたいということなんで書いた。改行も試験したいのでこんなに長い文になってしまった。')
document.add_heading(u'見出し２', level=2)
document.add_paragraph(u'本文２')
document.add_heading(u'見出し３', level=3)
document.add_paragraph(u'本文３')

document.add_picture(str(fig_path/'test.png'), width=Inches(1.25))
pg = document.add_paragraph(u'Figure',style='Caption')
Figure(u'図の名称',pg)

document.add_page_break()

document.save(word_path/'demo.docx')
```

Comment: OSは何ですか？Wordのバージョンは何ですか？

Comment: またコードはimport文から記入されると回答者が再現しやすくなります。モジュールのバージョンについても追記ください。

Comment: OS等のversionを追記させて頂きました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問のコードを実行したところ「SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal」が発生しましたのでコードをご確認ください。先のエラーを修正したところで別のエラー「NameError: name 'document' is not defined」も発生しましたのでこちらも確認いただき質問のコードを修正お願いします。

Comment: Word側のスタイルの設定に依るかと思いますので、スタイルの設定がどうなっているのかも追記いただくと回答しやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: コードを該当部分だけでなく全部載せさせて頂きました。
wordのスタイルはデフォルトのままで、図番号だけ「図 1」ではなく「Figure 1」のように変更しています。

Comment: 「wordのスタイルはデフォルトのままで」とのことですが、こちらでは「document.add_heading(u'見出し１', level=1)」のところで「KeyError: "no style with name 'Heading 1'"」が発生してしまい先へ進めませんでした。使用したWordのバージョンが2021でしたのでそのせいかもしれません。お役に立てず残念です。他の回答者の回答をお待ちください。